# How to flash the program using ATLINK/V2 UART communication

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, stm32f7, stm32f0

I am using ST-LINK/V2 RoHS module in this module we have 20 Pins.
without SWCLK and SWDIO pin I need to program.
[enter image description here][1]

in this following pin diagram we have RX and TX can we flash the program using that.
let me know

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The image (or image link) is missing from your question. Can you update the question with the image link?

Comment: Which STM32 board or MCU is this about? Don't just add tags randomly. Please remove the ones that do not apply.